# Strange error in Xcode: Code Signing Operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, signing

[image: This is the dialogbox i get when, trying to upload my app to the AppStore]

This is the dialogbox i get when, trying to upload my app to the AppStore

My codesigning in xcode looks like this:

[image]

I have been redownloading the distribution certificetes and provision profiles.
I have also been reinstalling xcode several times.

Any other one who have been into this error before?

Please help me :-)

btw i am using xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Are you compiling it or debugging the application?  To debug you need a developing certificate.  Distribution certificates are for publishing.

Comment: maybe you could just try pasting that into the terminal after `codesign` and see if you get useful output

Comment: Its not for debug, its for release and i am using a distribution certificate. @GradyPlayer which part should i paste?

Comment: There is a field inside your build settings, that says: Other Code Signing Flags. Have you added anything there?

Basically in the Code Signing section on your settings you should choose one certificate for the Debug (or however you named it) and one for the Release (or however you named it) profiles and maybe something on the Entitlements, if you have any.

Comment: i have edited the question and uploaded a picture of how it looks. Everything looks good but it still gives me the error... :(